# An inequality of weakly convergent series of singular measures

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I have a feeling this should work, but I can't find a proof. All measures are assumed to be regular Borel measures here.

If $\mu = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu_i$ is a series of mutually singular measures on some compact Hausdorff space $X$, that converges in the weak*-topology (or vague topology), that is
$$\mu(f) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu_i(f) \qquad \text{for all } f\in C(X). $$

Can we say that for a generic $f\in L^2(X, \mu)$ we have the inequality
$$||f||^2_\mu \geq \sum_{i=1}^\infty ||f||^2_{\mu_i}$$

where the norms are the $L^2$-norms? Does it hold if the $\mu_i$'s are finitely supported or/and $\mu$ is a probability measure and the space is sufficiently nice (like a compact metric spaces)?

Comment: You are taking about Borel measures (?) on a compact Hausdorff space which are not even finite on compact sets. I doubt if any theorem on vague topology applies to such measures.

Comment: Yes, right,  I forgot to say all measures are assumed to be regular Borel. I'm working on a problem where the limit $\mu$  is  known to be a probability measure, if that helps. Maybe I shouldn't have formulated it so general.

Comment: Why are considering measures with $\mu \{0\}=\infty$? Such measures are not regular.Also $\sum |mu_i$ is not a probability measure if $\mu_i$ 's are. Such a sum is rarely a regular measure so the whole question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I will removed the example, since it seems to be confusing. It was the idea I had in mind, and I was wondering if it was true in a general setting. Though I didn't say the $\mu_i$'s where probability measures, you are free to make any assumption on the space (metric space, compactness, etc..) for the question to make sense to you. The ergodic decomposition theorem should then supply enough examples of convergent seres of this form.

Comment: This is already false for the sum of two unit point masses and $f\equiv 1$: the inequality reads as $\sqrt{2} \ge 1 + 1$.

Comment: Ahh.. your absolutely right, I forgot to square the norms there.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone reads this, the answer is unfortunately no. For metric spaces the [Portmanteau theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) gives conditions under which the inequality holds.